# Backpressure on WebClient - applying backpressure to inter-service async web requests

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

The description below summarizes my novice attempt at applying backpressure on webclient.

Scenario 1: Applying limitRate() on reactive mongodb response. Service #1 runs on port 8080 on my machine

Code:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/getBooks/{name}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Book> getBooks(@PathVariable("name") final String name)
    {
        //SERVICE #1

        return bookRepo.findByBookName(name)
                .log()
                .limitRate(3);
    }
```

Logs:

```
2022-10-04 13:52:28.919  INFO 38716 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2022-10-04 13:52:28.932  INFO 38716 --- [  restartedMain] c.example.demo.ReactiveDemoApplication   : Started ReactiveDemoApplication in 3.538 seconds (JVM running for 4.198)
2022-10-04 13:58:20.363  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onSubscribe(FluxUsingWhen.UsingWhenSubscriber)
2022-10-04 13:58:20.366  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : request(3)
2022-10-04 13:58:20.424  INFO 38716 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:276}] to localhost:27017
2022-10-04 13:58:20.474  INFO 38716 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=1, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.491  INFO 38716 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=2, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.492  INFO 38716 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=3, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.554  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : request(3)
2022-10-04 13:58:20.555  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=4, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.555  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=5, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.555  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=6, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))

and so on .. until :

2022-10-04 13:58:20.561  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=14, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.561  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=15, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.562  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=16, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 13:58:20.566  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onComplete()
2022-10-04 13:58:20.568  INFO 38716 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : request(3)
```

Scenario 2: Applying limitRate() on Service #2's webclient response. Service #2 calls Service #1.  Service #1 runs on port 8080 on my machine

Code:

Service #1 endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/getBooks/{name}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Book> getBooks(@PathVariable("name") final String name)
    {
        //SERVICE #1
 
        return bookRepo.findByBookName(name)
                .log();
    }
```

Service #2:

```
@GetMapping("/getBooks")
    public Flux<Book> getBooks() {

        // SERVICE #2

        return webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/getBooks/bn2")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Book.class)
                .log()
                .limitRate(3);
    }
```

Logs:  SERVICE #1

```
2022-10-04 16:36:45.386  INFO 17520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2022-10-04 16:36:45.397  INFO 17520 --- [  restartedMain] c.example.demo.ReactiveDemoApplication   : Started ReactiveDemoApplication in 4.894 seconds (JVM running for 6.311)
2022-10-04 16:42:21.718  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onSubscribe(FluxUsingWhen.UsingWhenSubscriber)
2022-10-04 16:42:21.720  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : request(1)
2022-10-04 16:42:21.782  INFO 17520 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:7}] to localhost:27017
2022-10-04 16:42:21.840  INFO 17520 --- [ntLoopGroup-3-3] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=1, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.913  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : request(31)
2022-10-04 16:42:21.914  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=2, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.915  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=3, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.916  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=4, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.917  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=5, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.918  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=6, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.919  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=7, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.920  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=8, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.921  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=10, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.921  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=11, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.922  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=12, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.923  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=13, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.923  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=14, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.924  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=15, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.925  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(Book(id=16, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:42:21.931  INFO 17520 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onComplete()
```

logs: SERVICE #2

```
2022-10-04 16:45:26.291  INFO 27496 --- [  restartedMain] c.example.demo.ReactiveDemo3Application  : Started ReactiveDemo3Application in 3.507 seconds (JVM running for 4.1)
2022-10-04 16:45:43.159  INFO 27496 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1           : onSubscribe(MonoFlatMapMany.FlatMapManyMain)
2022-10-04 16:45:43.163  INFO 27496 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1           : request(3)
2022-10-04 16:45:43.845  INFO 27496 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1           : onNext(Book(id=1, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:45:43.875  INFO 27496 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1           : onNext(Book(id=2, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:45:43.876  INFO 27496 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1           : onNext(Book(id=3, bookName=bn2, authorName=an))
2022-10-04 16:45:45.924  INFO 27496 --- [     parallel-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.1           : request(3)

and so on..
```

I was expecting request(3) like Scenario 1,  but this time i see request(1) and request (31).
Even after adding delay in SERVICE #2 , the Logs remain the same. :-

```
 return webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/getBooks/bn2")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Book.class)
                .log()
                .limitRate(3)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
```

What am i missing?

EDIT 1: I am getting similar results with subscriber-controlled backpressure.

Answer (score 1):

It could be hard to control backpreasure using `limitRate` and `delayElements`. If your goal is to have more granular control on number of requests, I would suggest to look at recilience4j [RateLimiter](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter). It's fully reactive and could be integrated into the flow using `RateLimiterOperator`

```
RateLimiterConfig rateLimiterConfig = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
        .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .limitForPeriod(2) // 2 requests per second
        .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
        .build();

RateLimiterRegistry registry = RateLimiterRegistry.of(rateLimiterConfig);

RateLimiter rateLimiter = registry.rateLimiter("WebClient");

webClient.get()
     .uri("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/getBooks/bn2")
     .retrieve()
     .bodyToFlux(Book.class)
     .transform(RateLimiterOperator.of(rateLimiter));
```

Comment: I agree. RateLimiter gives you better control over what is going on. Additionally, instead of hardcoding it, it can be configured in your application.yml and reused by multiple webClients in your application. You should really give it a try.